# Shortcuts in PyCharm for moving to the previous line of code?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

Hitting Alt+Enter moves to the next line. Is there any shortcut to say move from line 17 to line 16?

Answer (score 1):

To start a line above your current line press: Ctrl+Alt+Enter